# Killing all Python processes that are using either of the GPUs

Tags: nvidia, python, process, kill, ps

I have the following and I don't want to enter the PID of each Python process that uses either of GPUs one by one. How can I do so?

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2722      G   /usr/bin/X                          9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2971      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update: I used both `killall` and `killall python3.8` and none worked:

```
[jalal@goku ~]$ nvidia-smi
Thu Jun 10 19:29:19 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.67       Driver Version: 460.67       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P2    59W / 250W |    843MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P2    61W / 250W |    826MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2722      G   /usr/bin/X                          9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2971      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[jalal@goku ~]$ killall python3.8
[jalal@goku ~]$ nvidia-smi
Thu Jun 10 19:29:26 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.67       Driver Version: 460.67       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:05:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P2    59W / 250W |    843MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P2    62W / 250W |    826MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2722      G   /usr/bin/X                          9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2971      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      1831      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2266      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2612      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2758      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     20403      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     21616      C   python3.8                         137MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[jalal@goku ~]$ killall
Usage: killall [-Z CONTEXT] [-u USER] [ -eIgiqrvw ] [ -SIGNAL ] NAME...
       killall -l, --list
       killall -V, --version

  -e,--exact          require exact match for very long names
  -I,--ignore-case    case insensitive process name match
  -g,--process-group  kill process group instead of process
  -y,--younger-than   kill processes younger than TIME
  -o,--older-than     kill processes older than TIME
  -i,--interactive    ask for confirmation before killing
  -l,--list           list all known signal names
  -q,--quiet          don't print complaints
  -r,--regexp         interpret NAME as an extended regular expression
  -s,--signal SIGNAL  send this signal instead of SIGTERM
  -u,--user USER      kill only process(es) running as USER
  -v,--verbose        report if the signal was successfully sent
  -V,--version        display version information
  -w,--wait           wait for processes to die
  -Z,--context REGEXP kill only process(es) having context
                      (must precede other arguments)
```

Comment: One of the reasons I like `killall` but I don't really understand your question as are you trying to kill gnome-shell too? (you've listed it)

Comment: What command gives you that output? Which of those processes do you want to kill?

Comment: the point is exactly not to kill gnome-shell and only kill python processes without entering their PIDs @guiverc

Comment: As I stated in first commend; I'd use `killall`  or `killall python3.8` in that example.  Use `man killall` to read your options (which are many, including using patterns).  As I don't know what your paste was I don't know if you'll need to adjust the command

Comment: @guiverc please check the updated post

Comment: Sorry I don't know what the `nvidia-smi` shows and currently used boxes are all AMD so I can't explore what it likely is.. so cannot help with how to interpret what it's actually showing and thus the required option you'll need (answer may only be path is also need `/usr/bin/python3.8` for example; but I don't know `nvidia-smi` sorry; I'd use `ps` myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ killall -9 python3.8
```

Here, SIGKILL (9) will force it to exit.

Credits to `VG9t`